# Spacing multiple adject selecters on desktop and mobile

Tags: css

I have 2 or more `<a>` tags and I'm trying to ensure that they have `margin-right` on desktop view and some `margin-top` on mobile view. I can figure out the media query portion in the base CSS.

I'm pretty sure that `a + a + a` won't work but if it would, it would become messy, especially in my case where I have 5 links in a row.

I can't always use flex, so that may not be an option.

What would be the right approach in this case?

Comment: Please provide an example of your code

Comment: This question is very unspecific as to what the _actual_ problem is. Please provide a proper [mre], plus an explicit description of what you want to have margins where, and what not. Not sure why you mentioned `a + a + a` in relation to this, but `:nth-child` might be a more flexible alternative to that. And for “only the first / last element in each row should not have a margin” or something like that, there’s also solutions that simply offset that by a negative margin on the container element.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below code:

```
@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
    a{margin-right:20px;}
    a:last-of-type{margin-right:0px}
}
@media screen and (max-width:799px) {
    a{margin-top:20px;}
    a:first-of-type{margin-top:0px}
}
```

Media queries and margin, you may change as per your requirements.